# how to specify WPF panel that shows DataGrid and row of buttons always under the DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I been using Grid where 1st GridRow has Height="*" and 2nd row has horizontal Stackpanel with 2 buttons and Height="Auto". This has disadvantage that when DataGrid has only few rows the button-row is still in the bottom of the Grid i.e the available area.

I can't use Auto for 1st row because when lots of rows the button-row cannot be seen anymore.

Same with using StackPanel.

So how could I have button-row always visible and always right below the DataGrid?

Comment: how can somebody close-vote question this specific? i'd really appreciate somebody telling me what's wrong with this.

Comment: If your button row is disappearing than your overall layout structure has some issues higher in its DOM. Would need to see more of the overall layout to give a good response. As for the close-vote I can't speak to that, there's a few folks around here that go to that pretty quick but I can at least put ya back at 0 ;)

Comment: put you DataGrid and Button row in a dock panel and dock the buttons to the bottom before you dock your DataGrid, also ensuring you set the vertical scroll bar visibility to auto on your DataGrid

Comment: @ChrisW. The very reason I didn't include the code was that the visual structure is so complex that the question would have been pages of xaml and explanation. I totally agree that this is difficult to say why things are happening when not seeing the whole structure. I was hoping the best that with info provided there could be a solution. And thanks for +1 :)

Comment: @stuicidle: this worked in a way that now button row is right under the table but the table takes all the available space  even if only few rows. so the effect is almost same. thanks for your answer though!

Comment: The overall container should be a DockPanel, and set the height of your DataGrid to auto